# In iOS 10 , UISearch bar height is increasing when editing. Its working fine in iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, uisearchbar

Following is the code to configure search bar:

**Code:**

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
searchBarContainerView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
```

Its working fine in iOS 9.

[image: iOS 9]

But in iOS 10 its height is increasing suddenly and overlapping the header.

[image: iOS 10]

Comment: Height is increasing while editing or searchBar overlaps with header after the view is loaded?

Comment: As we can differntiate from area of dark gray color of search bar. Its increasing in iOS 10. @Sathi

Comment: please check autolayout constraints once. There might be some problem..